# Linear systems, eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, determinant

For each of the following linear systems of differential equations, 
(i) find the general real solution
(ii) show that the solutions are linearly independent
(iii) draw the phase portrait

a. $$\dot x=\begin{bmatrix}6&-3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}x$$

find the characteristic equation:
$$(6-λ)(1-λ)-(-3*2)=0$$
$$(λ-3)(λ-4)=0$$
with roots $λ_1=3$ and $λ_2=4$

for the eigenvalue, $λ_1=3$:
$$(A-λ_1I)v_1=(A-3I)v_1=0$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}6&-3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}-3\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}v_1$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}3&-3\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}v_1$$

row reduced form: $$=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}v_1=0$$

find the eigenvector $v_1$: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=0$$
$$a-b=0$$
$$a=b$$
$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

first solution: $x_1(t)=e^{3t}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

for the eigenvalue, $λ_2=4$:
$$(A-λ_2I)v_2=(A-4I)v_2=0$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}6&-3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}-4\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}v_2$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}2&-3\\2&-3\end{bmatrix}v_2$$

row reduced form: $$=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}v_2=0$$

find the eigenvector $v_2$: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=0$$
$$a-b=0$$
$$a=b$$
$$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

second solution: $x_2(t)=e^{4t}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

matrix solution: $\begin{bmatrix}e^{3t}2e^{4t}\\e^{3t}&3e^{4t}\end{bmatrix}$

wronskian: 
$$W(t)=det\begin{bmatrix}e^{3t}&2e^{4t}\\e^{3t}&3e^{4t}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=e^{7t}$$

t=0:

$$W(O)=det(v_1,v_2)=det\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}=1$$

So it's linearly independent.

I am really unsure about my work for the eigenvector,does this look correcT? If not, could you explain how I would find the eigenvector?

(I know I am not done answering the problem, still working through it)

Comment: If you get zero as the only solution for an eigenvector, it must be wrong.  I have no idea how you got your row reduced form, as far as I can see it is just a careless error.  Please try it again.

Comment: @Amzoti yea im a little bit confused about row reduction, can you check my row reduction for the other one?

Comment: @Amzoti thanks!